# What database should I use in this condition? Or should I use them at all?

Tags: javascript, html, database

I have created a simple project with two  HTML page 'home' and 'details'. I have a spreadsheet of some data I want to show as list in 'home' page and on clicking shows associated details. I tried searching in internet but I was left with even more question than before. The data consist of 10 column and 1000 rows and might reach 5000 rows.

Comment: What's the issue here?

Comment: I want to show selected row in detail page but writing html code for 1000 row would be impossible. I checked some solution in internet and found databases complex and difficult to learn.

Comment: What do you want us to do?

Comment: Can you please recommend me some simple database to start learning? I'm really lost here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing trouble while learning DataBase, there is an alternative you can try and it is very easy to understand and implement in your code.
You can learn about JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), Simply you have to create a JSON file in which you can store the detail of all those 1000-5000 rows and render them on your Web page using JavaScript